# Can you run a Heroku worker process with Node & Express

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I'm trying to run a Worker process on Heroku with NO web process.

It is a small node express app. But it does not work unless I have a web process running.

I have a Procfile with

`worker node server.js`

But I get this error

`heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/`

I want to run it as a worker process as workers are not restricted to the 30s timeout and should be more efficient. This endpoint is meant to just process 1 intensive task separate from our main API so it makes sense to be setup as a worker.

As per this

https://help.heroku.com/PFSOIDTR/why-am-i-seeing-h12-request-timeouts-high-response-times-in-my-app

> Question 2: Have I delegated long-running tasks as background jobs? If
>   you cant make your code run any faster and you simply need more time
>   (i.e. process images, parsing documents, making API calls, etc), you
>   can run them as background jobs on worker dynos. Worker dynos do not
>   face the same 30 second timeout that web dynos do, making them perfect
>   for heavy lifting.

All issues I find on fixing this says scale to web:1

So this leads me to believe express cannot run as a worker only and must be a web process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-configurations) on Heroku's website, `worker` dynos do not expose any ports. If you want to have an endpoint that is reachable through the web, you will have to use a `web` dyno. You can, though, achieve what you want by communicating web and worker dynos with a **queue protocol**, as explained in [this answer by Ryan Daigle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429774/how-to-communicate-web-and-worker-dynos-with-node-js-on-heroku).

Comment: Thanks, yeah that makes sense. No HTTP calls means Express won't work on anything but Web. I have worked it out by using Redis as a message broker between the Web and Worker processes and its working very well!